# How to load part of data set efficiently based on time index in R

Tags: r, csv, processing-efficiency, read.csv

I'm often working with several `.csv` files, having a size of `>100MB`; however, in many cases I only need a subset of the data. The subset is always within a certain time interval. My question is if there's a function or way in R so that I can only load a subset of the data, not knowing the index of the timetags?

This is how I usually do it:

Imagine I have a `.csv` file called `Large_CSV_file.csv` and I have minute timestamps of 20 years length in the first column and data in the second.

```
# Load entire data set
dat <- read.csv("Large_CSV_file.csv")
# Find idx where to cut the data set
start.idx <- which(dat[,1] == as.Date("01-01-1990"))
end.idx <- which(dat[,1] == as.Date("01-01-1991"))
# Subset of data set
dat <- dat[start.idx:end.idx,]
```

The first line of code is the one that takes a lot of time to load and I feel it's not efficient to load the entire data set, before discarding 99% of it...

Comment: I don't know R myself but in Java you can seek thru the text file and search for the interesting line before reading it...I think in most language file searching/reading is most fundamental. Hopes this idea helps.

Comment: Try using `fread` for speed. You can use the `colClasses` argument to say you only want the first column. That might help you specify start and stop points. You could use a shell command to work those out if you want speed.

Comment: @sebastian-c - thanks I'll have a look at the fread class (I'm already using colClasses to avoid unused cols)

Comment: I should mention that it comes from the `data.table` package. If you're dealing with large chunks of data, `data.table` is the way to go anyway.

Comment: @sebastian-c fread definitely speeds up the process; moreover, the ``skip`` functions makes it possible to skip lines and is a clearly step into the right direction